# In Calabash-Android, How do I press the 1st Item in a RecyclerView?

Tags: android, calabash

They deprecated their touch listview method.  I can't find anywhere in the documents to press the 0th item

Comment: Touching on listview is not deprecated I guess. More-over touching of listview will not help you to identify pressing on 1st Item in RecyclerView. You need to work a little bit with ID of the individual view appearing on recycler view Item index. I guess some Calabash expert can tell you about that.